# Como relacionar duas estruturas de dados do tipo lista

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto para entender melhor estrutura de dados, no projeto está sendo utilizado **estrutura de dados do tipo lista** e nele devo cadastrar alunos e após o cadastrado, posso escolher qualquer aluno que esteja cadastrado para incluir uma quantidade n de livros, esses livros também são ordenados por uma **estrutura própria** que apontam sempre para o próximo ou para seu final.

No meu desenvolvimentos consigo realizar o cadastrado de alunos porém travo na hora de fazer a relação e o apontamento de alunos para livros no momento em que decido cadastrar os livros.

Estou disponibilizando todo código fonte desenvolvido, ele está todo comentado possuindo uma navegação fácil do que está sendo feito, **mas especificamente a criação do livro se encontra na linha 355.**

[Código](http://ideone.com/OhMSXo)

---

### **Adendos para melhorar o entendimento**

[image: Cada aluno possui sua própria lista de livros construída por uma struct]

Comment: Eu queria comentar a sua publicação, mas eu não tenho reputação suficiente. Então isso aqui não é uma resposta, só quero entender a sua dúvida. Você tem uma lista encadeada de alunos, certo? E cada aluno está relacionado a alguns livros. E cada aluno estará ligado a uma lista encadeada de livros, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso Gabriel, acabei de adicionar uma imagem para transmitir melhor essa ideia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou te ajudar a partir desse canal de respostas, ok?

Você comentou que está com um erro na linha 178 do seu código. 
O seu problema é não atualizar o valor de aux, ou seja, o seu while-statement nunca para porque aux nunca troca de valor. A ideia seria a seguinte:

```
while(aux != NULL) {

    if(cod_aluno == aux->aluno.codigo) { 
         if(aux->inicLivro != NULL)
            inicio = removeOrdenado(inicio, cod_aluno);
         else
             printf("O aluno não pode ser removido, pois possui livros em sua conta.");
    }
    else 
         aux = aux->proximo;

}
```

Agora, lendo o bug relatado na linha 222, você percorre a lista, e mesmo se você acha, você atualiza aux, o que não precisa ser feito, você deveria utilizar um if/else. A variável "cot" é dispensável, e o seu IF final não é impresso nunca porque se você não achou aquele código, o valor de aux é NULL. 
O código deveria ser:

```
struct listaAluno *aux;
int cod_aluno;

aux = inicio;


    if(aux == NULL)
{
    printf("Não há alunos cadastrados no sistema.");
    printf("\nImpossivel realizar consulta.");
}
else
{
    printf("\nLocalizar Aluno\n");
    printf("Informe o código do aluno: ");
    scanf("%i", &cod_aluno);

    while(aux != NULL)
    { 
        if(cod_aluno == aux->aluno.codigo)
        {
            printf("\nCódigo: %d | Nome: %s | Curso: %s",  aux->aluno.codigo, aux->aluno.nome, aux->aluno.curso);
        }
        else 
            aux = aux->proximo;
    }
}

if(aux == NULL)
{
    printf("O código informado não pertece a nenhum aluno cadastrado no sistema.");
}
```

E bem, quanto ao problema da lista encadeada dentro de outra lista encadeada, eu trabalhei com isso já em alguns laboratórios, e eu não segui a sua ideia de estruturas. Você montou 4 structs, 2 pra listas e 2 pra nós. 
O jeito que eu aprendi e me dei muito bem fazendo usa apenas os nós, e para aumentar a eficiência da lista usa a técnica de nós "dummy", são nós que não tem função e são os primeiros da lista, e servem, por exemplo, para facilitar remoções e inserções na primeira vez que elas são ocorridas. 
(recomendo a leitura: https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html)

Ademais, como você quer trabalhar com remoções e inserções no início e no fim, eu sugiro usar uma struct de controle, que contem as posições do início e do fim da lista.

Sendo assim, em pseudocódigo, as estruturas seriam:

```
struct Aluno { 
  informações do aluno;
  ponteiro para o próximo aluno;
  ponteiro para sua lista de livros;
}
struct Livro { 
 informações do livro;
 ponteiro para o próximo livro;
}
struct Controle {
 informações da lista (quantidade de nós, entre outros); //opcional
 ponteiro para o início da lista;
 ponteiro para o fim da lista;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por ver os outros erros que estavam presentes e por me passar esse material, irei ler e modificar o que precisa ser modificado. Não entendi muito bem o uso do Controle, mas acredito que o material irá tirar minhas dúvidas, qualquer coisa entro em contato.